# Change widget state in list remotely

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on a `GridView` that builds a `Container` widget for every item in a list.

```
new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 1.3,
        children: cardSet.map((card){
        Color containerColor = Colors.blue;
        return new GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
          setState(){
           containerColor = Colors.green;
           //This part is unsolved:
           containerColor.of(matchingWidget) = Colors.green;
          };
          }
          child: new Container(
            color: containerColor,
          ),
        );
          }).toList()),
```

So here is my problem: I would like the user to find matching values in the GridView, and since each `Container` holds one value each, selecting two values with `onTap` either results in matching values or non-matching values. In both cases, the color of the two selected `Container` widgets is supposed to change.

Changing the last selected `Container` widget is easy, just by changing the `color` property with `setState()`, how do I change the color of the previously selected, 'matching' container though? To use the image, how would I change both the color of the 'two' and the '2' container simultaneously, after the user tapped on the matching 'two' container?

Do I use a `key` property to store a reference to the 'matching' widget or is there another possibility?

[image: GridView]

Comment: Could you share your code more?

Comment: @yahocho I just updated the code snippet with the relevant part that I would like to solve. Basically it comes down to changing the `containerColor` of the matching container (if the match is indeed correct, like '2' and 'two') simultaneously to changing the color of the last tapped container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made `class myCard` as below:

```
class myCard {
  String key;
  Color color;
  String match;

  myCard( {
    this.key,
    this.color,
    this.match
  });
}
```

And, created `cardSet` list as below:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var cardSet = [
    myCard(key:"two", color:Colors.blue, match:"2"),
    myCard(key:"3", color:Colors.blue, match:"three"),
    myCard(key:"one", color:Colors.blue, match:"1"),
    myCard(key:"2", color:Colors.blue, match:"two"),
    myCard(key:"10", color:Colors.blue, match:"ten"),
    myCard(key:"ten", color:Colors.blue, match:"10"),
    myCard(key:"three", color:Colors.blue, match:"3"),
    myCard(key:"1", color:Colors.blue, match:"one"),
  ];
```

I think you can make it by your style. Actually, We can call `myCard` as model.

And I made `getMatchCard` function finding out related card.

```
  myCard getMatchCard(card){
    return cardSet.where((_card)=>_card.match==card.key).toList()[0];
  }
```

Finally, I set a color of card in `setState` by `myColor`'s attributes. 
`containerColor` was local variable and its data was not able to be kept. So, I thought that we need member variables to keep data after creating all `GestureDetector`.

```
child: new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    childAspectRatio: 1.3,
    children: cardSet.map((card){
      return new GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          setState((){
            card.color = Colors.green; // a color of Tapped card
            getMatchCard(card).color = Colors.green; // a color of related card
          });
        },
         child: new Container(
           color: card.color,
           child:Text(card.key) // I set the text in myself because I can not see your cardSet data.
         ),
      );
    }).toList()),
```

You know, Flutter derives the reactive programming. So, Separating `model` and `view by state` is comfortable.

It works well. Please refer the image as below:
[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your extended explanation!